# Airflow: pass {{ ds }} as param to PostgresOperator

Tags: python, scheduler, airflow

i would like to use execution date as parameter to my sql file:

i tried

```
dt = '{{ ds }}'

s3_to_redshift = PostgresOperator(
    task_id='s3_to_redshift',
    postgres_conn_id='redshift',
    sql='s3_to_redshift.sql',
    params={'file': dt},
    dag=dag
)
```

but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

`dt = '{{ ds }}'`

Doesn't work because Jinja (the templating engine used within airflow) does not process the entire Dag definition file.

For each `Operator` there are fields which Jinja will process, which are part of the definition of the operator itself.

In this case, you can make the `params` field (which is actually called `parameters`, make sure to change this) templated if you extend the `PostgresOperator` like this:

```py
class MyPostgresOperator(PostgresOperator):
    template_fields = ('sql','parameters')
```

Now you should be able to do:

```py
s3_to_redshift = MyPostgresOperator(
    task_id='s3_to_redshift',
    postgres_conn_id='redshift',
    sql='s3_to_redshift.sql',
    parameters={'file': '{{ ds }}'},
    dag=dag
)
```

Comment: Note the templating doesn't protect against sql injection. For building sql statement from smaller parts, which is probably OP's case, templating (or string manipulation) is unavoidable. For simple substitution of parameter value, `@()s` syntax provides more safety. Example: `task = PostgresOperator(task_id='task_default_connection', sql='insert into test.foo(id,hoo) values (2,%(hoopar)s)', parameters={"hoopar":"v2"}, dag=dag)`

Comment: @jhnclvr Would with your code this line work then: `parameters={'file': dt},`?

Comment: I tried this and doesn't work: https://gist.github.com/fpopic/666ad772d90ba5b78767e82724f59130

Comment: @TomášZáluský Really appreciate the comment. Do you have any references that explain more about how this replacement method works? "@()s" .. I am curious to learn more about this it doesn't seem documented anywhere

Comment: I tried this too but doesn't work. The '{{ ds }}' is parsed as empty string.

Answer (score -1):

PostgresOperator / JDBCOperator inherit from BaseOperator.
One of the input parameters of BaseOperator is params:
   
   `self.params = params or {}  # Available in templates!`

So, you should be able to use it without creating a new class:
(even though params is not included into template_fields)
    
    `t1 = JdbcOperator(
         task_id='copy',
         sql='copy.sql',
         jdbc_conn_id='connection_name',
         params={'schema_name':'public'},
         dag=dag
    )`

SQL statement (copy.sql) might look like:
    
    `copy {{ params.schema_name }}.table_name
    from 's3://.../table_name.csv'
    iam_role 'arn:aws:iam::<acc_num>:role/<role_name>'
    csv
    IGNOREHEADER 1`

Note:

copy.sql resides at the same location where the DAG is located.
OR
you can define "template_searchpath" variable in "default_args"
 and specify absolute path to the folder where template file resides.
For example: 'template_searchpath': '/home/user/airflow/templates/'