# How can I pass ds derived params to the hive sql operator in airflow

Tags: python, jinja2, airflow

With Airflow I want to run a query that returns all the data for a given period, based on the ds. The ds is always my end date, but the start date can vary. It can for example be a week or a complete month. To handle that I want to create different dags with a schedule that runs either montly or weekly.
So far so good. 
However, I run into troubles when I want to pass the start_dt

in my sql template I have this:

```
where report_dt between '{{ params.report_start_dt }}' AND '{{ds}}'
```

In the monthly dag I want to pass the report start_dt as such:

```
monthly_profile = HiveOperator(
            hql= mycode.sql
            params={**args,
                'report_start_dt': '{{ (execution_date.replace(day=1)).strftime("%Y-%m-%d") }}',
                },
            task_id='monthly_profile',
            )
```

However this fails since the template does not handle nested variables I guess.

Rendered template:

```
where event_dt between {{ (execution_date.replace(day=1)).strftime("%Y-%m-%d") }} AND  '2019-07-31'
```

I have seen this post: [Airflow: pass {{ ds }} as param to PostgresOperator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44523567/airflow-pass-ds-as-param-to-postgresoperator) 
but according to me I am doing the same, allbeit for an hiveoperator.

What am I doing wrong and how can I achieve what I need, keeping in mind that I also want to do it with a simple offset of the ds with 7 days for my weekly run?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are trying to use python libraries for the data manipulation within you template. The jinja2 is not able to understand what you want, that is why you are getting the that rendered template.

You can get around this problem by using Hive SQL functions, and just pass argument to those functions. So for the start of the month you can use like:

```
date_add(FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(), 'yyyy-MM-dd'),
         1 - day(FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(), 'yyyy-MM-dd')) 
        )
```

And in airflow:

```
monthly_profile = HiveOperator(
            hql= mycode.sql
            task_id='monthly_profile',
            )
```

In the SQL file

```
    where report_dt between date_add(day('{{ execution_date }}','%Y-%m-%d'),
               1 - day('{{ execution_date }}','%Y-%m-%d'))                       
          AND '{{ds}}'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is indeed something that I can work with. Nevertheless I do not understand the exact issue. For example I found this piece of text on the web:

The BashOperator bash_command argument is a template. You can access execution_date in any template as a datetime object using the execution_date variable. In the template, you can use any jinja2 methods to manipulate it. Using the following as your BashOperator bash_command string, for example:
# pass in the first of the current month
some_command.sh {{ execution_date.replace(day=1) }}

Comment: Anyway, thanks again, I will implement your solution.

Comment: Still I run into an issue in fact. If I adapt the SQL template I want to in fact offset the number of days. So for the beginning of the month it should be 1 - day('{{ds}}') . But for my weekly run it is simply "7". I will run then into the same issue that I cannot pass the ds like that, even  with a default I don't know how to achieve this:
`BETWEEN DATE_ADD('{{ds}}',{{ params.report_start_dt_offset | default("1-day(ds)") }} AND  '{{ds}}'`

Comment: Well, currently I have a working workaround indeed, it covers my use cases.
`DATE_ADD('{{ds}}',{{ params.report_start_dt_offset | default("1-day('" + ds + "')") }} )  ` For the weekly run I just feed the ofset parameter with 7