# Airflow Template Not Rendering

Tags: python, airflow

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44523567/airflow-pass-ds-as-param-to-postgresoperator/44548570#44548570) answer, I wrote a custom Operator to include name and args parameters as template-able fields:

```
class TemplatedLivyOperator(LivyOperator):
    template_fields = ('name','args', 'spark_params',)
```

And I'm trying to get execution date through a template within this custom Operator:

```
    op = TemplatedLivyOperator(
        dag=dag,
        task_id='test1',
        livy_conn_id='livy_default',
        name="run1_" + str(datetime.fromisoformat('{{ ts }}').strftime('%Y-%m-%d-%H')),
        args=[substrate,env,str(datetime.fromisoformat('{{ ts }}').strftime('%Y-%m-%d-%H'))]
    )
```

However, I am getting `ValueError: Invalid isoformat string: '{{ ts }}'` so {{ ts }} isn't being replaced with the execution date. Any ideas here? Don't want to use a separate PythonOperator to get the execution date.

Comment: Where is that second snippet of code located?  It needs to be in a file that is interpreted by Jinja.

Comment: @TimRoberts both of the above code snippets are located in my DAG definition file